# How to intentionally fray curved edges in fabric?

Tags: sewing, cutting, fabric

<sup>**Closely Related:**

- [How to Sew Up "Cut Outs", (Shapes Cut Into Fabrics)?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/3374/how-to-sew-up-cut-outs-shapes-cut-into-fabrics)</sup>

[In the related question](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/3374/how-to-sew-up-cut-outs-shapes-cut-into-fabrics), there are solutions for prevent frayed edges in fabric.

But, could you avoid the complexity of sealing, folding, or stitching those edges - by intentionally leaving "nice" ***pre-frayed edges***?

*Example:* If you were to cut a circle ***into*** the fabric, and stitched closely (1cm??) from the ***curved edge*** - what methods could be used to leave a "consistently" frayed edge?

Are the fabric's "weave", "thread-count", or other factors, important for this?

Comment: Between this and your previous question about how to **stop** the edges from fraying, there are so many variables up in the air now that you just need to fool around with your ideas and make a few samples and see what works and what you like.

Answer (score 8):

You have the right idea. Sewing near the edge but leaving the actual edge raw will achieve a frayed edge. Things to keep in mind:

1. This will only work on a woven fabric, not a knit.
2. Most importantly, not all edges will fray equally on a circle shape. Because of the nature of a woven fabric, the threads are horizontal and vertical. Certain places around the circle (mostly when you hit the bias area), the fraying will change or may not show up at all.
3. The weave does matter. If the fabric has a very open weave, it may not have a very frayed look, but look like loose threads.

Answer (score 0):

I would *stay stitch* close to my intended edge and manually snip the fray. Easy peasy.

Answer (score 0):

On some items that were a no-sew diy that I want to make with burlap an I wanted to have with very lil freying so on the back side I squeezed tacky glue in a real fine & slim line around the burlap shape I wanted; an right before the glue started to draw good I took my finger making it flat an smooth to where was not visible from the front and it stopped freying everywhere inside the glue shape an i cut about 1/8 excess past my glue line shape to create a freyed edge but solid every where else ! I know this works for burlap type fabrics but as for other fabrics that are going to be sewed I am not sure ! I'm not on my silhouette Cameo machine I have a great cutting blade that does a wonderful job on every fabric I have tried so far...